# Delayed Job returns no method error [ ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Trying to upload a file using delayed job

```
def import
  @report = current_user.reports.create!(name: params[:report_name])
  @contact = @report.contacts.delay.import(params[:file], params[:info_type])
  flash[:success]= "Contacts importing, check back in 2-3 minutes"
  redirect_to contacts_url
end
```

returns:

```
undefined method `import' for []
```

When I try without the association:

```
def import
  @report = current_user.reports.create!(name: params[:report_name])
  Contact.delay.import(params[:file], params[:info_type], @report.id)
  flash[:success]= "Contacts importing, check back in 2-3 minutes"
  redirect_to contacts_url
end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Import:

```
def self.import(file, info, report_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
        input = row*""
        # input = hashy["input"]
        case info
        when "email"
            begin
                contact_hash = FullContact.person(email: input)
                if contact_hash.status = 200
                    Contact.create!(input: input, contact_hash: contact_hash.to_json, info_type: info, found: true, pending: false, report_id: report_id) 
                elsif contact_hash.status = 202
                    Contact.create!(input: input, contact_hash: contact_hash.to_json , info_type: info, found: true, pending: true, report_id: report_id) 
                end
            rescue FullContact::NotFound 
                Contact.create!(input: input, contact_hash: nil, info_type: info, found: false, report_id: report_id)
            rescue FullContact::Invalid
            end
        when "telephone"
            begin
            Contact.create!(input: input, contact_hash: FullContact.person(phone: input).to_json, info_type: info, report_id: report) 
            rescue FullContact::NotFound 
                Contact.create!(input: input, contact_hash: "Not Found", info_type: info, report_id: report)
            rescue FullContact::Invalid
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I should also not that I am using the gmaps4rails gem, which defaults columns latitude, longitude and gmaps as nil until the contact is saved into the database. Is that why?

Comment: Where is this `import` defined? Are you sure the error message is occurring due to the `import` method? What does the delayed job `import` method look like?

Comment: please always post the callstack of your errors. from what you write, i think that you should re-read the delayed_job documentation. it usually uses the `.delay` method on an instance of a model like `@user.delay.something`. so `something` would be a method of the `User` class and that class is configured to work with DJ

Comment: @phoet where can i find the callstack of errors?

Comment: @phoet I did that here, but it didn't return an error, just didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205947/delayed-job-not-executing-on-rails-3-2-14-dj-4-0-0

Comment: @mbratch it's defined in the contact model. DJ doesn't have import method.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy yep I'm aware of that. Poor wording on my part. I meant to know what the `import` method looks like that's being used for the DJ.

Comment: I will edit the question now and post. Also, just discovered that it can't find the DJ log file: log/delayed_job.log: No such file or directory when I call: tail -f log/delayed_job.log

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.import`. It will work instead of just `import`

```
def self.import

end
```

Comment: Aren't I already doing that? or are you saying calling .delay.self.import?

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `import' for "dcc36a923c445d1ddb6970ec":String

Comment: Sorry, turns out I was getting the error above because I had Sidekiq gem running too. I got rid of that, now I am getting: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass